# Android view on top of Button and EditText doesn't obscure them

Tags: android, android-layout

This one was a bit unexpected for me. I have the following layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hello" />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/MyEditText"
    android:layout_below="@id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hello" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I was expecting the LinearLayout to obscure part of both views (The button and the EditText. The result in the emulator is exactly that:

[image: emulator screenshot]

However on the device (A Moto G 3rd Generation), the button is shown on top of the LinearLayout:

[image: result on the device]

Furthermore, I can still tap the button and the EditText on the parts that should be obscured by the LinearLayout on both, the device and the emulator.

[image: clicking on the controls behind the linear layout]

My questions then are: How can I make the linear layout appear on top of the button on the device? And how can I prevent taps on the LinearLayout from being redirected to the button and edit text?

Thank you.

Just in case, I'm using Xamarin for Android but it shouldn't be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can I make the linear layout appear on top of the button on the device?**

Elevation is what's causing the `Button` to appear in front of the `LinearLayout`. Views with a higher elevation appear in front. It works in the emulator because there you're using a pre-Material design version of Android.

See: http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

"To set the elevation of a view in a layout definition, use the `android:elevation` attribute. To set the elevation of a view in the code of an activity, use the `View.setElevation()` method."

**How can I prevent taps on the LinearLayout from being redirected to the button and edit text?**

By using `android:clickable="true"` on `LinearLayout`. Reason is, if `LinearLayout` is not clickable, the clicks are eventually dispatched to views that are further back.

Comment: Thank you. Adding android:elevation="10dp" to the LinearLayout fixed the button overlapping. However taps on the linear layout are still handled by the button or the edittext. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is `LinearLayout` isn't capturing click events so they then get dispatched to views that are further back. Have you tried setting `android:clickable="true"` on the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: Yes, adding both attributes fixed both the problems. Thank you very much.